# Why does Workbooks.Add trigger an Error 91?

Tags: excel, vba

For many years/versions you could easily create new workbooks in Excel from an existing book using

```
Dim newbook As Workbook
Set newbook=Workbooks.Add
```

I am now getting problems with this. The code still runs and the workbook opens, but it sets Err to be 91 ("Object variable or With block variable not set").

A subsequent

```
Err.Clear
```

seems to work and `newbook` can be used as normal, but not sure why the error is thrown in the first place.

Comment: Where do you have your above code? Can you show the snippet with event trigger?

Comment: Those lines are all the code for this part. I am inspecting the value of Err through the debugger and it changes on the Set line above.

Comment: What are the lines following the `Set` line? Most likely you are trying to do something in a previous workbook that doesn't exist in the workbook you just created.

Comment: I tried your code on Office Pro 2019, no error occurs. New Work Book is always smoothly created. Is your error because of your installation?